# Using | for python re

Tags: python, regex

I have tag id ABxxx, where x are any digits.  In this tag, there can be spaces before AB, in between (AB) with unlimited space after, or have AB_. See list below.

1. `(AB)_xxx`
2. `(AB)_xxx`
3. `AB_xxx`
4. `(AB)  xxx`
5. `ABxxx`

I want to get tuple pairs for each tag. I created a re expression to get those.

```
tag=re.compile(r'\s*\(*(AB)\)*\s*\_ (\d{2,3})\s*$',re.VERBOSE).match('AB_678').groups()
print(tag)
```

Result is `('AB', '678')`.

But now I want to exclude the following formats:

1. `(AB_xxx`
2. `AB xxx`

I adjusted the `re` statement by including the non-capturing group syntax and the OR operator.

```
tag=re.compile(r'^\s*(?:(AB | \(AB\)\s* | AB\_ | \(AB\)\_)) (\d{2,3})\s*$',re.VERBOSE).match('(AB)_678').groups()
print(tag)
```

After trying `(AB_xxx` , it gave me the error, which i want.  Except now if I try the acceptable conditions, it would include the () or _ in my tuple. 
 For example : `'(AB)_678'` would result `('(AB)_', '678')`

I understand I'm using `?:` for the entire `AB` Or statements, which is why it's pulling the additional non-special characters.

I tried putting () around each criteria but now it's giving me extra tuple elements for each criteria : `(None, None, 'AB', None, '678')`.

```
tag=re.compile(r'^\s*(?:(AB) | \((AB)\)\s* | (AB)\_ | \((AB)\)\_) (\d{2,3})\s*$',re.VERBOSE).match('AB_678').groups()
print(tag)
```

Not quite sure where to go here.  Do I have the right approach so far?

Comment: Do you check these ID tags on their own or do you need to pick them out of a larger string?

Comment: Out of a larger string or list.  I just simplified the code a bit to make it easier to understand what I need help with.

Comment: This work for your test cases: `(\(AB\)(?:_| *)|(?<!\()AB_?)(\d+)\b` - Give me a second to figure out your expressions.

Comment: (Note that this is written for `re.VERBOSE`; personally I never use verbose mode.)

Comment: I'm fairly new to learning re still, and examples I've learned from have been using re.verbose. Any particular reason you don't recommend it?

Comment: If you know that the first group can contain parentheses, spaces and underscores, just replace them after matching with `str.replace()` instead of making the regex more complicated. That's not worth it.

Comment: Verbose mode is primarily meant for structuring the regex nicely on multiple lines with indentation and comments what each part means (you're not doing that, so that's a wasted opportunity) - but it's not supported by all regex engines. In fact, most of them don't have it. And I've grown used to reading regex as they are. There's nothing wrong with it, though. I've just mentioned it because my expression won't work with verbose mode on.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  I saw that when I was trying out your code in comment #3.  I noticed it was still giving me results as my 2nd code in the original post.

Comment: It only matches the right strings here: https://regex101.com/r/gZe42c/1 - unless I've misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: Oh yea. it definitely matches.  My last requirement is to just get rid of the non alphanumeric values in the tuple.  For example: AB_111 would be ('AB', '111),  and not ('AB_','111')

Comment: Using str.replace() would definitely make this so much easier.  But I want it so that only limited specific formats work instead of applying str.replace on all parenthesis, spaces, and underscores.

Comment: That won't be possible. Either the group count increases because your regex matches different alternatives into distinct groups, or your group count stays at 2 because you handle different alternatives *inside* the first group. In the second case your group will contain unwanted characters, there is no way to avoid that. In the first case the group count won't be 2, and there is no way to avoid that, either. Take your pick.

Comment: To conclude, you will need a look-behind `(?<!\()` to prevent matching `(AB_xxx` in a two-group regex.

Comment: yea I noticed I was switching between the two situations and couldn't get them to combine.  I'll need to look outside of regex then.

Comment: thanks for all the valuable insight on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the below regex works for me

```
^(AB|(?:\((?:AB)\)))(?:_|\s{2,})?(\d{2,3})
```

Breaking it down into three pieces

**^(AB|(?:((?:AB))))**

Match `AB` or `(AB)` at the start

**(?:_|\s{2,})?**

Look for a `_` or minimum 2 spaces or nothing

**(\d{2,3})**

Get a two or three digit number

Tested on `regex101.com` to make sure it matches only valid cases and not invalid ones

[image: RegExTest]

The only issue with this is your group would be `AB` or `(AB)`. to make it always capture `AB` would make the regex complex and this can be easily handled by your python code